# Using gui textfield for custom resolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help please, I try to add a custom resolution changer in c# with unity gui.

```
this.WeightRez = GUI.TextField(new Rect(300f, 250f, 90f, 25f), this.WeightRez, 6);

if (GUI.Button(new Rect(350f, 0f, 0f, 0f), ""))
{
    if (int.TryParse(this.WeightRez, out this.WeightRezFloat))
    {
        this.WeightRezFloat = int.Parse(this.WeightRez);
    } else {
        this.HeightRez = "ERROR";
    }
}

this.HeightRez = GUI.TextField(new Rect(260f, 0f, 90f, 25f), this.HeightRez, 6);

if (GUI.Button(new Rect(300f, 230f, 90f, 0f), ""))
{
    if (int.TryParse(this.HeightRez, out this.HeightRezFloat))
    {
        this.HeightRezFloat = int.Parse(this.HeightRez);
    } else {
        this.HeightRez = "ERROR";
    }
}

if (GUI.Button(new Rect(450f, 0f, 120f, 25f), "Set"))
{
    Screen.SetResolution(this.WeightRezFloat, this.HeightRezFloat, true);
}
```

It wont work
Thanks if you can help me

Comment: Are you geting an error or unxpected behavior? 
Could eloborate more a little bit on your question which part exactly doesn't work.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I can compile it, but in game, when I write my custom resolution then press "set", wont work, I keep getting my current resolution

Comment: Did you try to write out or debug the parameters states when you press "set"?

Comment: just for clarity, you tried after building it and not just in play mode? because it wont do anything in play mode ... also please switch to uGUI, its 2019. with textmesh-pro enabled (its a free package you only need to use), you even get nifty input fields that let you input only numbers (you still only get a string back, tho)

Comment: @Daniil T write out